# How to make OpenVPN connection not expire after 24h?

Tags: vpn, openvpn

So I'm connecting to a VPN server from Ubuntu 16.04 via

```
$ sudo openvpn client.ovpn
```

And client.ovpn starts with

```
# Automatically generated OpenVPN client config file
# Generated on Mon Jun  6 10:36:29 2016 by openvpnas
# Note: this configuration is user-locked to the username below
...
# OVPN_ACCESS_SERVER_CLI_PREF_ALLOW_WEB_IMPORT=True
# OVPN_ACCESS_SERVER_CLI_PREF_BASIC_CLIENT=False
# OVPN_ACCESS_SERVER_CLI_PREF_ENABLE_CONNECT=True
# OVPN_ACCESS_SERVER_CLI_PREF_ENABLE_XD_PROXY=True
...
# OVPN_ACCESS_SERVER_WEB_CA_BUNDLE_START
# -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
# -----END CERTIFICATE-----
# OVPN_ACCESS_SERVER_WEB_CA_BUNDLE_STOP
# OVPN_ACCESS_SERVER_IS_OPENVPN_WEB_CA=1
# OVPN_ACCESS_SERVER_ORGANIZATION=OpenVPN Technologies, Inc.
setenv FORWARD_COMPATIBLE 1
client
server-poll-timeout 4
nobind
...
dev tun
dev-type tun
ns-cert-type server
reneg-sec 604800
sndbuf 100000
rcvbuf 100000
auth-user-pass
# NOTE: LZO commands are pushed by the Access Server at connect time.
# NOTE: The below line doesn't disable LZO.
comp-lzo no
verb 3
setenv PUSH_PEER_INFO
```

The connection terminates after 24 hours automatically. How do I make it persistent? Is there an option for that I can pass to `openvpn`?

Comment: Do you have an internet connection with an automatic disconnect after 24h on the client side? Eg. about every german DSL connection ...

Comment: No, mine is persistent. It's only VPN connection that expires.

Comment: What is in your logs?

Comment: Is there a reason to connect like that? I mean the openvpn itself can be configured as a service to act like server or client. That way the connection will be persistent all the time. ?

Comment: Even as a service, the connection expires. Syslog reads `AUTH: Received control message: AUTH_FAILED,SESSION: Your session has expired, please reauthenticate`

Comment: @Pavel did you find a way?

Comment: I didn't. I guess it's a security issue and needs to be resolved on the server side.